# Get all function names of specific smart contract ABI

Tags: ethereumjs, abi

I just want to get list of function names from smart contract abi. Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
let AbiJson = `Your ABI JSON string`

let abi = JSON.parse(AbiJson);

for(let item of abi) {
    if(item.name)
        console.log(item.name);
}
```